# Discrete Fourier Transform is not working for me in OpenCV 3.1

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I am new to OpenCV. Currently, I am using version 3.1.

I was trying to implement the DFT using the exact code written in the [OpenCV doc for DFT](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html#discretfouriertransform), but I am getting an error in the `Mat_<float>(padded)` part:

[image: following error I am getting]

The image I am using for testing is JPEG, 3 channel, 8 bit.

Please let me know if I am doing any mistake.

```
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 Mat rawImg = imread("E:/sample.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); // 50x50 jpeg     
 Mat padded;                            //expand input image to optimal size
 int m = getOptimalDFTSize(rawImg.rows);
 int n = getOptimalDFTSize(rawImg.cols);
 cout << "rows :" << m << endl;
 cout << "cols :" << n << endl;
 copyMakeBorder(rawImg, padded, 0, m - rawImg.rows, 0, n - rawImg.cols,     BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar::all(0));
 Mat planes[] = {Mat_<float>(padded),Mat::zeros(padded.size(),CV_32F)};
 Mat complexI;
 merge(planes, 2, complexI);         // Add to the expanded another plane with zeros

 dft(complexI, complexI);            // this way the result may fit in the source matrix

split(complexI, planes);                   // planes[0] = Re(DFT(I), planes[1] = Im(DFT(I))
magnitude(planes[0], planes[1], planes[0]);// planes[0] = magnitude
Mat magI = planes[0];

magI += Scalar::all(1);                    // switch to logarithmic scale
log(magI, magI);

// crop the spectrum, if it has an odd number of rows or columns
magI = magI(Rect(0, 0, magI.cols & -2, magI.rows & -2));

/** As my input image is 50x50 it has no extra pixel to delete I have ommited this part from the original code
**/

normalize(magI, magI, 0, 1, CV_MINMAX); // Transform the matrix with float values into a
// viewable image form (float between values 0 and 1).

imshow("Input Image", rawImg);    // Show the result
imshow("spectrum magnitude", magI);
waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show your actual code. The example should work well (tested with OpenCV 2.4.9 and 3.0). Are you using Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: I have added  the code now @Miki please review. Yes I am using Visual Studio 2013